# Subsetting a list in R

Tags: r, list

I am working with a list p that looks like this:

```
p
$AAANWWTGC_UNKNOWN
  [1] "4208"   "481"    "6095"   "10370"  "351"    

$AAAYRNCTG_UNKNOWN
  [1] "4052"   "9842"   "23047"  "55800"  "1942"   
$MYOD_01
  [1] "23630"  "84668"  "3151"   "26523"  "667"    

$E47_01
  [1] "90523"  "84668"  "26523"  "154807" "1942"
```

I would like to filter p so as to obtain another list, say q, retaining only elements from list p that contain at least one character from a given vector, for instance:

```
v<-c("4052","1942")
```

Thus, the new list q in this specific example should look like:

```
q
$AAAYRNCTG_UNKNOWN
      [1] "4052"   "9842"   "23047"  "55800"  "1942"  
$E47_01
      [1] "90523"  "84668"  "26523"  "154807" "1942"
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Filter` from `base R`

```
Filter(function(x) any(v %in% x), p)
#$AAAYRNCTG_UNKNOWN
#[1] "4052"   "9842"   "23047"  "55800"  "1942"  
#$E47_01
#[1] "90523"  "84668"  "26523"  "154807" "1942"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to count the matches using `purrr`'s `keep` function included in the `tidyverse`. Then subset the list which have more than `0`.

```
library(tidyverse)
list(c( "4208" ,  "481"    ,"6095"   ,"10370"  ,"351"    ),
     c( "4052" ,  "9842",   "23047",  "55800" , "1942"),
     c("23630",  "84668" , "3151"   ,"26523",  "667"),
     c("90523" , "84668" , "26523" , "154807" ,"1942" )) %>% 
  keep(function(x) sum(x %in% v) > 0)
[[1]]
[1] "4052"  "9842"  "23047" "55800" "1942" 

[[2]]
[1] "90523"  "84668"  "26523"  "154807" "1942"
```

Comment: It worked and the result was consistent with that from @akrun suggestion. Thanks